# Merge 2 array same key

Tags: php, arrays

I'd like to merge two arrays on same key. I've tried my best to do it but unable to get success. I've added both the Arrays below. Kindly check both the Arrays in detail and help me how to merge it using same key.

**Here's the 1st array :**

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [costprice1] => 500
            [margin1] => 20

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [costprice2] => 600
            [margin2] => 15

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [costprice3] => 700
            [margin3] => 25

        )

)
```

**Here's the 2 array :**

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (

            [entityType1] => Products1
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [entityType2] => Products2
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [entityType3] => Products3
        )
)
```

i want to need like that array please suggestion me

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (

            [entityType1] => Products1
            [costprice1] => 500
            [margin1] => 20
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [entityType2] => Products2
            [costprice2] => 600
            [margin2] => 15
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [entityType3] => Products3
            [costprice3] => 700
            [margin3] => 25
        )
)
```

please help me how to merge two array

Comment: Can you provide the code showing what your best attempt was? StackOverflow is more for helping people with specific questions/problems than for general answers (and people will downvote your question for such) so if you can provide some context of where you got to that would help us.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
foreach($array1 as $key => $value) {
    $array1[$key]['entityType'.$key] = $array2[$key]['entityType'.$key];
}
print_r($array1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$array1 = [
  1 => [
    'costprice1' => 500,
    'margin1' => 20
  ],
  2 => [
    'costprice2' => 600,
    'margin2' => 15
  ],
  3 => [
    'costprice2' => 700,
    'margin2' => 25
  ],
];

$array2 = [
  1 => ['entityType1' => 'Products1'],
  2 => ['entityType2' => 'Products2'],
  3 => ['entityType3' => 'Products3'],
];

array_walk($array2, function(&$v, $k)use($array1){
    $v = array_merge($v, $array1[$k]);
});

print_r($array2);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [entityType1] => Products1
            [costprice1] => 500
            [margin1] => 20
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [entityType2] => Products2
            [costprice2] => 600
            [margin2] => 15
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [entityType3] => Products3
            [costprice2] => 700
            [margin2] => 25
        )

)
```

https://eval.in/618561

Comment: thank u Bert for help me your suggestion is working but key should be start 1

Comment: bert i have need array key start with 1

Comment: You can use array_unshift() with an empty array. This is cause the first array to be empty.